# Cannot write SQlteAssethelper in my project

Tags: android

I have included all the required dependenciesstill I cannot write sqliteasset helpe, I have included

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
```

Why I cannot call sqliteassethelper,

Comment: Never use just a plus as a version number

Comment: Plus, look at the README, it's no longer maintained. Perhaps you can try Android Room library?

Comment: I changed the plus version to 2.0.1 still it doesntworks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was ale to solve this

If you are using the old build system, download the latest library JAR and put it in your project's libs folder.

Comment: What do you mean "old build system"? Sound like you're still using Gradle... If that JAR was removed from the Maven repo (which is where Gradle downloads it from), then you shouldn't be able to do this anyway